# ggmap: create circle symbol where radius represents distance (miles or km)

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying to add a circle around a given latitude and longitude point where the circle size (radius) reflects distance in miles or km.

I managed to come up with this example using ggmap, where I can add a circle. but what do I need to do to have it represent distance. I would ultimately like the bounds of the circle to represent 20 miles from the center.

Code below:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(lat=c(33.79245),
                lon=c(-84.32130))

emory <- get_map("Atlanta,Georgia", zoom=12)

p <- ggmap(emory)
p <- p + geom_point(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat),
                    color="red", size=20, alpha=0.5)
p
```

Comment: Can we plot cluster inside this circle with different colors?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/124664)

Answer (score 8):

The actual problem is to plot a circle with 40 miles in diameter on a map with a lat/lon projection (typically [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/)), because native map units are degrees. Therefore, it seems to me the simplest solution is to work with a different projection that is based on meters (that can easily be converted to miles) rather than degrees.
As an alternative to `get_map`, you could work with `gmap` from the **dismo** package that also allows the retrieval of Google Maps data. I have to confess that `get_map` results in a higher spatial resolution and is easier to handle when working with `ggplot`, but for demonstration purposes, `gmap` should do the trick as well. Anyway, retrieving the data from Google Maps works quite similar...

```
# Google Map of Atlanta
library(dismo)

emory <- gmap("Atlanta,Georgia", zoom = 10, scale = 2)
```

Next, you should transform your central location into a true spatial object by defining `coordinates` and `projection`. For subsequent buffering and plotting purposes, you need to reproject it to the coordinate reference system (CRS) of the Google Maps 'RasterLayer' object.

```
d <- data.frame(lat = c(33.79245), lon = c(-84.32130))

coordinates(d) <- ~ lon + lat
projection(d) <- "+init=epsg:4326"

d_mrc <- spTransform(d, CRS = CRS(projection(emory)))
```

Now that you transformed your lat/lon location into [Google's Mercator projection](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SphericalMercator) that comes in metres, you could define a little helper function that converts miles to meters (or you just use an online conversion tool). Based on the thus derived distance in metres, `gBuffer` from the **rgeos** package will create a circular-shaped 'SpatialPolygons' object .

```
# Miles to meters conversion
mile2meter <- function(x) {
  x * 1609.344
}

# Buffer creation
d_mrc_bff <- gBuffer(d_mrc, width = mile2meter(20))
```

Now that you have assembled everything you need, it's finally time for plotting.

```
library(scales) # for `alpha()` function

plot(emory)
plot(d_mrc_bff, col = alpha("blue", .35), add = TRUE)
points(d_mrc, cex = 2, pch = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response flowla!This is what I was looking for. I am quite new to mapping and particularly mapping with R. I am having trouble learning all about projections and which ones to use and when. Ultimately I want to try this technique of adding distance buffers (circles) to maps using Rgooglemaps but for now this is great!  Thanks again for your help!