# Creating Concentric circles using the ggmap function from GGMAP package R

Tags: r, scale, ggmap

I would like to create two concentric circles using the ggmap package and `ggmap` function, one being 1/4 mile and the other 1 mile radius around the 16 metro rail stations in Los Angeles California. It looks like `ggmap` doesn't scale the size in `geom_point(aes(size=1))` to miles, so I would like to know how to convert this to miles. (I looked at the dismo package but I would like to use ggmap to do this.)

```
library(ggmap)

d = matrix(c(-118.2342,  34.05620,
       -118.2461,   34.05490,
       -118.2513,   34.04932,
       -118.2587,   34.04863,
       -118.2749,   34.05637,
       -118.2901,   34.06270,
       -118.2917,   34.07653,
       -118.2917,   34.08991,
       -118.2918,   34.09771,
       -118.3081,   34.10174,
       -118.3252,   34.10163,
       -118.3385,   34.10155,
       -118.3627,   34.14000,
       -118.3768,   34.16850,
       -118.3015,   34.06175,
       -118.3088,   34.06169), 16, 2, byrow=T)

colnames(d) = c("long", "lat")
d = data.frame(d)


m = get_map(location = "Hollywood,California", maptype = "roadmap", zoom = 12)
la_map = ggmap(m)
# HERE I WANT TO ADD A RADIUS OF 1 MILE and A RADIUS OF 1/4 MILE OVER THAT. 
la_map +
geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, size = 1, col = "blue"), data = d) +
geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, size = 1/4 ,col = "red"), data = d)
```

Comment: This may be helpful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/119736/8104

Comment: Hey Aaron, thanks for the reply. I already looked at the link you sent before i posted this question, and thats why i posted this question, the link uses something different to arrive at the solution, and i couldn't do further improvements to that plot, on the other hand with ggmaps it would be a different case with all the "geom_" that one can add to the ggmap, he uses plot() and i want to know if i can do that in ggmap(). thanks